# Contrapositive proof: If $H$ and $K$ are nontrivial subgroups of $\Bbb Q$, then $H\cap K$ is also nontrivial.

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, rational-numbers

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra,"* by Gallian.

This is (part of) Exercise 26 of the supplementary exercises for chapters 1-4 *ibid.*, although **I am requesting a proof of the contrapositive** just out of interest, **preferably using prior material available from the textbook.**

**I intend to use abstract algebra, keeping in the spirit of the textbook; thus proofs that rely on, say, real analysis (too much), will not be accepted.**

> $\mathcal{O}$: Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are nontrivial subgroups of $\Bbb Q$ under addition. Show that $H \cap K$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\Bbb Q$.

The contrapositive problem can be stated as follows:

> $\mathcal{C}$: Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $\Bbb Q$. Suppose $H\cap K=\{0\}$ is trivial. Show that either $H$ or $K$ is trivial.

---

*Thoughts:*

To me, it seems $\mathcal{C}$ is one of those things that are so tauntingly "obvious", it's hard to know where to begin.

My problem is also that my only thought I have worth sharing for this is to *try* assuming - no joke! - that neither $H$ nor $K$ is trivial, then deducing $H\cap K$ is nontrivial, contradicting the hypothesis that $H\cap K=\{0\}$. That's just silly.

---

A lovely proof of the original statement $\mathcal{O}$ is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2013489/104041), with variations on its theme [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238744/104041) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238739/104041).

Please help :)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2013489/104041) proves the result in the title, @DonAntonio (assuming $\Bbb Q$ is indeed under addition). Here's what I want: an algebraic proof of the contrapositive $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{O}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ denote the property that triviality of an intersection of two subgroups implies triviality of either.

1: If all $G_i$ have the property $P$, then so does

$$\lim_{\longrightarrow}G_i .$$

2: Define  $\mathbb{Z}^{(n)}=\mathbb{Z}$, and for $n|m$,

\begin{align}
f_{n,m}:\mathbb{Z}^{(n)} &\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{(m)}, \\
k &\mapsto\frac{m}{n}\cdot k.
\end{align}

Then
$$\mathbb{Q}=\lim_{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}^{(n)}.$$

3: $\mathbb{Z}$ has the property $P$. In fact, $H\cap K=0$ implies the injectivity of
$$\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/H \times \mathbb{Z}/K,$$
and thus $H=0$ or $K=0$.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7):

This follows from the fact that any two rational non-zero numbers $a/b$ and $c/d$ have a common multiple, say
$$
cb \cdot \frac{a}{b} = ad \cdot \frac{c}{d}.
$$

It will be unnatural to give a proof using abstract algebra only, as this is a simple arithmetic fact depending on specific properties of rational numbers.

Comment: This just describes what the proofs linked to in the question for $\mathcal{O}$, so it doesn't prove $\mathcal{C}$ directly nor is it in the spirit of my question. (Hence the downvote.)

Comment: The property you want to prove is very specific to $\mathbb{Q},$ so it is unlikely you'll find a proof using 'abstract algebra' (whatever that exactly means). The proof I give is really the core of the problem, I think.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for me, a mere PhD student, to define what exactly "abstract algebra" is. Most people with an undergraduate degree in some mathematical field has some idea what it means. Besides, you might want to revise things like a [field of fractions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions). Also, again, please see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085770/contrapositive-proof-if-h-and-k-are-nontrivial-subgroups-of-bbb-q-then?__=942989307#comment6362155_3085805) and the answer linked to in the opening post for why your answer is not helpful.

Comment: Sorry that I, a mere math PhD, could not be more helpful... Joking aside, I think the thing you want does not exist.

Comment: Of course you can try to suitably generalize the statement to field of fractions, but the proof itself will not be different in its core. If you are indeed looking for a more general statement, then you have to re-phrase your question.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3086934/104041) by @HiroWat does the job. This comment is to bring it to your attention, Reiner :)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected